# Is there a java 11 native way to convert json to an object?

Tags: java, json

This question: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) Has several answers which require including 3rd party libraries, including GSON, org.json and Jackson.

I am using Adobe AEM, which is notoriously intolerant of including 3rd party libraries, so am trying to do the REST API calling with standard Java 11.  java 11 has the HTTPClient classes, which will give me JSON from the response.

Now I need to convert Json into the required java object.

E.g. I have a Person class with name and age fields, and want to get a Person object from something like {"name":"bob", "age":12}

I will also need something to convert a Java object into Json.

Any suggestions?

There is something called JsonObject in java 7, but I have not been able to find any examples which show this conversion.

Comment: Looks like a runtime third party library dependency is needed. Which is frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JsonB](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/bind/Jsonb.html) which was introduced in JavaEE 8

```java
import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;

Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
Person person = jsonb.fromJson(personString, Person.class);
```

If you use `maven`, here is the dependencies to add

```xml
<!-- JSON-B API -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JSON-B RI -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
  <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My IDE doesnt find this type, whats the package?  javax.json has things like jsonBuilderFactory, but I cant find jsonb or JsonBuilder?

Comment: I also tried  importing from javax, but get "The import javax.json.bind cannot be resolved".  Googling this it says you get this with java 7, but I have java 11. Is it not in java 11?

Comment: Yes, you are right! In fact, it is JavaEE API. I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Whats "RI"?  Do I need jasson?  Do I also need     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>?

Comment: In fact, in JavaEE we have APIs and Impls. **RI** stands for reference implementation

Comment: And as I know, **yasson** is the only implementation of the JSON-B API

Comment: Bizarrely when I add "Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(); to any one servlet , all spring servlets stop working, and give:

Resource at '/bin/demo/querybuilder' not found: No resource found
Cannot serve request to /bin/demo/querybuilder in BundledScriptServlet (/libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp)

Request Progress:
      0 TIMER_START{Request Processing}
     21 COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed microseconds>,<timer name>} <optional message>
     43 LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=null

Error.log nas nothing (other than the 404), and there are no build errors.